# Can I use taco seasoning in chicken quesadillas?

Tags: chicken

When cooking the chicken for quesadillas would it be ok to use taco seasoning to give some flavor to the chicken? Would that taste weird? I have a new quesadilla maker I will be using tonight?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The Tex-Mex Seasoning Bill of 1988 specifically prohibits the interchange of seasonings between different dishes. Thanks Obama!* *may be sarcasm

Answer (score 1):

Yes, yes you can.

Recipes aren't like alchemy**.  You can adjust flavorings to suit your taste.

You're correct to add it when cooking the chicken ... if you just tried to add it when assembling, the flavors won't meld, the flavors won't fully develop, and it can be a bit ... chalky ... when it's obvious that there's a powder coating.

** unless of course, you're baking ... then it is like alchemy, and what seems like alittle change can make a huge difference in the finished item or ruin it completely.

Answer (score 1):

Taco Seasoning creates a  wonderful taste sensation for Chicken quesadillas.

I would recommend rubbing it into the chicken vs sprinkling it on. I find rubbing the seasoning in gives a much better flavour through out and reduces the chance of powdery residue or texture.

Word of caution Taco Seasoning doesn't blend well with poultry seasoning. Use one or the other.